Make bat file with several commands that take time for each
I would like to make a bat file but with several commands that each take some time.
I Haven't written a bat file in about 20 years
I would appreciate some examples.
I want run:
1 open command window
2 Command1
3 Wait until finished
4 Command2
5 And so on.
6 Then exit command

wating until the command is finished before going to next command is the default you don't need to do anything to make that  happen, if you want to futhure delay stuff you can use the /timeout /t 10 for example to delay something in 10 seconds...

Ahh is it that simple :) Ytied and it works thanks!

@RicardoBohner, that could be made into an answer -- it really does answer the question. You could add a reference, such as https://www.wikihow.com/Delay-a-Batch-File

Adding comment as an answer because this helped a lot :
"waiting until the command is finished before going to next command is the default you don't need to do anything to make that happen, if you want to further delay stuff you can use the /timeout /t 10 for example to delay something in 10 seconds."
